# How to solve key error in nested representation of a model in django

Tags: python, django, serialization

This is my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ID = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel,related_name='NewModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.BigIntegerField()
    duration = models.BigIntegerField(default= 30)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

where OtherModel has 2 fields, biginteger and foreignkey. I am trying to create an instance of the MyModel and it gives me a key error. The serializer is as below:

```
class ModifyReadingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    duration =  serializers.IntegerField()
    start =  serializers.IntegerField()

class OriginalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timePeriod = ModifyReadingSerializer(source = '*')
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('timePeriod', 'value',)
```

And the view to create it shown below:

```
class RegisterValues(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ''' GET/POST  urltemp/{ID = pk}'''
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OriginalSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        s1 = OtherModel.objects.get(mRID=kwargs["pk"])
        a_temp = MyModel.objects.create(
            ID=s1,
            value=request.data["value"],
            duration=request.data["duration"],
            start=request.data["start"],)
        return Response(data=OriginalSerializer(a_temp).data)
```

I get the following error KeyError at `/urltemp/1  'duration'`. I understand why I am getting the error but not sure how to fix it while maintaining the nested representation. And I can see the error is in the line where I am creating duration (I can see it in the terminal).

**EDIT: ADDED THE PAYLOAD**

```
{
    "timePeriod": {
        "duration": 30,
        "start": 24
    },
    "value": 34,
}
```

Comment: The key error raised because you didn't provided `duration` data on your post payload

Comment: I did it in my payload, I have uploaded the payload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet,

```
class RegisterValues(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ''' GET/POST  urltemp/{ID = pk}'''
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OriginalSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        s1 = OtherModel.objects.get(mRID=kwargs["pk"])
        a_temp = MyModel.objects.create(
            ID=s1,
            value=request.data["value"],
            duration=request.data["timePeriod"]["duration"],
            start=request.data["timePeriod"]["start"], )
        return Response(data=OriginalSerializer(a_temp).data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with your model structure. Since it's a `KeyError`, the problem is that there is no value in `request.data` associated with the key `duration`.

In other words, you must be calling your API without a field named `durantion` in the request body.

Make sure you to call the API endpoint including in the request body all the field you try to access in the your code and this error should disapear.

Comment: But there is a field named `duration`. It is in my model, I have put it in the question. And I think I am already doing what you are recommending.

Comment: JPG got it. After your edit it became clear that the problem was you were accessing the wrong key...